# Rust needs static lifetime when waiting on the same future?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-futures

I am trying to get the OAuth token from the server, so I made a struct named `Token`. In order to keep only one request when the token is expired, I keep a reference for the requesting future, let other requests keep waiting for it returns. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b089ddc2ebd02d245b43a07c394be808):

```
use futures::lock::Mutex; // 0.3.18
use futures_util::{future::Shared, Future, FutureExt}; // 0.3.18
use std::{pin::Pin, sync::Arc};
use tokio::time::Duration; // 1.14.0

pub struct Token {
    pub token: String,
    pub requesting:
        Arc<Mutex<Option<Shared<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<String, ()>> + Send>>>>>>,
}

impl Token {
    // Get token from server, I hope it does not run repeatly
    async fn get_access_token_from_server(&mut self) -> Result<String, ()> {
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(10)).await;
        self.token = "test".to_owned();
        Ok(self.token.clone())
    }

    //Shows error:`is required to live as long as `'static` here`, why?
    pub async fn access_token(&mut self) -> Result<String, ()> {
        /*
        if !self.token.is_expire() {
            return Ok(self.token.clone());
        }
        */

        let req_arc = self.requesting.clone();
        let req_mutex = req_arc.lock().await;

        let req = if req_mutex.is_some() {
            req_mutex.clone().map(|s| s.clone()).unwrap()
        } else {
            let req = self.get_access_token_from_server().boxed().shared();
            *req_mutex = Some(req.clone());
            req
        };

        req.await
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    /*
        Just example, in the real code, the token will keep in another struct with long life
    */
    let mut token = Token {
        token: String::from(""),
        requesting: Arc::new(Mutex::new(None)),
    };
    let token_string = token.access_token().await;
    println!("{:?}", token_string);
    Ok(())
}
```

I am confused about the lifetime errors:

```
error[E0759]: `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
  --> src/main.rs:21:31
   |
21 |     pub async fn access_token(&mut self) -> Result<String, ()> {
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^
   |                               |
   |                               this data with an anonymous lifetime `'_`...
   |                               ...is captured here...
...
35 |             *req_mutex = Some(req.clone());
   |                               ----------- ...and is required to live as long as `'static` here
```

I do not want to keep is as static; I hope its lifetime is the same as the struct.

1. Is the normal way to solve the problem?
2. How to correct the code?

Comment: The title needs to be edited to accurately reflect the issue. Also, a simplified code would be more helpful for others to understand and triage the issue.

Comment: @Joe_Jingyu I changed the title, the code is already simplified as much as I can. I added some comments to help understand. thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the compiler doesn't make it obvious where the constraint comes from. Storing a `dyn Future<...>` without any lifetime annotation defaults to `'static` and you can't really change it to the lifetime of `self` because self-referential structs are [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct).

Looking at your goal, you can use a thread-safe and `async`-capable [`OnceCell`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.14.0/tokio/sync/struct.OnceCell.html) (from tokio for example) and skip all this complexity.

```
use tokio::time::Duration;
use tokio::sync::OnceCell;

pub struct Token {
    pub token: OnceCell<String>,
}

impl Token {
    pub async fn access_token(&self) -> Result<&String, ()> {
        self.token.get_or_try_init(|| async {
            // simulate auth call
            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
            Ok("test".to_owned())
        }).await
    }
}
```

See it working on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=54d80d45329a55c1907bfa47283a037d).

I think it should behave as you expect. Multiple threads can `await` it but only one `async` task will execute and persist the value, and then any other `await`s will simply fetch that value. And if the task returns an error, the next `await` will retry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this case, the token may expire, so is there a better way to check (may update) and return using OnceCell?

Comment: In that case, you may still want it behind a `RwLock` so that you can still access it mutably and [`take()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.14.0/tokio/sync/struct.OnceCell.html#method.take) the value out of the cell, allowing it to reacquire the token.